Automatic Refresh Issue for Real-Time Dashboard in Power BI
I have prepared a dashboard with Power BI  that is hosted on a server and accessible to users through IIS. The issue I'm facing is that my dashboard is real-time, and it needs the browser page to refresh every five seconds to display new data.
I know there are some browser extensions that can be added to refresh the page every five seconds, but I don't want that.
I want the page to refresh itself without the user having to do any specific settings.
It's worth mentioning that the dashboard is written with direct queries, and in the desktop version, automatic refresh is fully established.

Can you specify your solution setup more? Are you using PowerBI report server on-premises? This might influence the solution(s) avaible. Thank you
